# FlutterWeb - how to store values in "shared preferences" - persistence

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, persistence, flutter-web

What's the **PREFERRED** alternative to `SharedPreferences` package that works on iOS/Android through platform channels?

I want to asynchronously **store key/value pairs in a persistent storage**. This would have to somehow call localStorage.getItem() & localStorage.setItem(key, value) from JS, I presume.

Package: https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

Flutter: Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.2, on Mac OS X 10.14.5 18F132, locale en-GB)

Comment: What's the question here? It is not yet implemented and cross web-mobile support is not yet added to Pub. Either you will have to find a Dart web package or write the code yourself, which would be good for future development.

Comment: Are there any plans for pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences to be available on FlutterWeb ? What's the proper way of invoking js code from Dart?

Answer (score 0):

For what's worth, they added the support to the web, you just need to import it in the pubspec.yaml file with

```
... dependencies: ... shared_preferences: ^0.5.4+8 shared_preferences_web: ^0.1.0 ...
```